# Upscaling/Downscaling provisioned RU for cosmos containers at specific time

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

As mentioned in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/how-to-provision-autoscale-throughput?tabs=api-async) there is support to increase/decrease the provisioned RU of cosmos containers using cosmosDB Java SDK but when I am trying to perform the steps I am getting below error:

```
com.azure.cosmos.CosmosException: {"innerErrorMessage":"\"Operation 'PUT' on resource 'offers' is not allowed through Azure Cosmos DB endpoint. Please switch on such operations for your account, or perform this operation through Azure Resource Manager, Azure Portal, Azure CLI or Azure Powershell\"\r\nActivityId: 86fcecc8-5938-46b1-857f-9d57b7, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0, StatusCode: Forbidden","cosmosDiagnostics":{"userAgent":"azsdk-java-cosmos/4.28.0 MacOSX/10.16 JRE/1.8.0_301","activityId":"86fcecc8-5938-46b1-857f-9d57b74c6ffe","requestLatencyInMs":89,"requestStartTimeUTC":"2022-07-28T05:34:40.471Z","requestEndTimeUTC":"2022-07-28T05:34:40.560Z","responseStatisticsList":[],"supplementalResponseStatisticsList":[],"addressResolutionStatistics":{},"regionsContacted":[],"retryContext":{"statusAndSubStatusCodes":null,"retryCount":0,"retryLatency":0},"metadataDiagnosticsContext":{"metadataDiagnosticList":null},"serializationDiagnosticsContext":{"serializationDiagnosticsList":null},"gatewayStatistics":{"sessionToken":null,"operationType":"Replace","resourceType":"Offer","statusCode":403,"subStatusCode":0,"requestCharge":"0.0","requestTimeline":[{"eventName":"connectionAcquired","startTimeUTC":"2022-07-28T05:34:40.472Z","durationInMicroSec":1000},{"eventName":"connectionConfigured","startTimeUTC":"2022-07-28T05:34:40.473Z","durationInMicroSec":0},{"eventName":"requestSent","startTimeUTC":"2022-07-28T05:34:40.473Z","durationInMicroSec":5000},{"eventName":"transitTime","startTimeUTC":"2022-07-28T05:34:40.478Z","durationInMicroSec":60000},{"eventName":"received","startTimeUTC":"2022-07-28T05:34:40.538Z","durationInMicroSec":1000}],"partitionKeyRangeId":null},"systemInformation":{"usedMemory":"71913 KB","availableMemory":"3656471 KB","systemCpuLoad":"empty","availableProcessors":8},"clientCfgs":{"id":1,"machineId":"uuid:248bb21a-d1eb-46a5-a29e-1a2f503d1162","connectionMode":"DIRECT","numberOfClients":1,"connCfg":{"rntbd":"(cto:PT5S, nrto:PT5S, icto:PT0S, ieto:PT1H, mcpe:130, mrpc:30, cer:false)","gw":"(cps:1000, nrto:PT1M, icto:PT1M, p:false)","other":"(ed: true, cs: false)"},"consistencyCfg":"(consistency: Session, mm: true, prgns: [])"}}}
at com.azure.cosmos.BridgeInternal.createCosmosException(BridgeInternal.java:486)
at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxGatewayStoreModel.validateOrThrow(RxGatewayStoreModel.java:440)
at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxGatewayStoreModel.lambda$toDocumentServiceResponse$0(RxGatewayStoreModel.java:347)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:106)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandle.java:119)
```

Message says to switch on such operations for your accounts but I could not find any page to do that. Can I use Azure functions to do the same thing at a specific time?

Code snippet:

```
CosmosAsyncContainer container = client.getDatabase("DatabaseName").getContainer("ContainerName"); 
ThroughputProperties autoscaleContainerThroughput = container.readThroughput().block().getProperties();
container.replaceThroughput(ThroughputProperties.createAutoscaledThroughput(newAutoscaleMaxThroughput)).block();
```

Comment: Can you attach the code? are you trying to use with AAD?

Comment: @Sajeetharan I am trying to execute below piece of code:

CosmosAsyncContainer container = client.getDatabase("DatabaseName").getContainer("ContainerName");
ThroughputProperties autoscaleContainerThroughput = container.readThroughput().block().getProperties();
container.replaceThroughput(ThroughputProperties.createAutoscaledThroughput(newAutoscaleMaxThroughput)).block();

Comment: Loooks to me like a issue due to policy or something, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/troubleshoot-forbidden#non-data-operations-are-not-allowed

Comment: @NishantMiddha - please *edit your question* to show relevant code. It's very difficult to read unformatted code, in a comment.

Comment: Also - as written, this question really has nothing to do with Azure Functions (I removed the tag, accordingly). Not sure about your question as to if you can use Azure Functions, as it's no different than running your code anywhere else...

Answer (score 0):

This is because `disableKeyBasedMetadataWriteAccess` is set to true on the account. You will need to contact either your subscription owner or someone with [DocumentDB Account Contributor](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#documentdb-account-contributor) to modify the throughput using [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/scripts/powershell/sql/throughput) or [azure cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/scripts/cli/sql/throughput), links to samples. You can also do this by redeploying the ARM template or Bicep file used to create the account (be sure to do a GET first on the resource so you don't accidentally change something.

If you are looking for a way to automatically scale resources up and down on a schedule, please refer to this sample here, [Scale Azure Cosmos DB throughput by using Azure Functions Timer trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql/scale-on-schedule)

To learn more about the `disableKeyBasedMetadataWriteAccess` property and it's impact to control plane operations from the data plane SDK's see, [Preventing changes from the Azure Cosmos DB SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/role-based-access-control#prevent-sdk-changes)